# Detecting arrival of push notifications in android app

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Is it possible to detect the arrival of push notifications programmatically on the android app? How should one proceed to implement the same?

Comment: what are you using to send the notifications to the phone? GCM, or some third-party client like UrbanAirship? Or are you trying to intercept all push notifications across other apps?

Comment: I am sending push notifications from Parse... I want to intercept only those push notifications. For this I have added GcmBroadcastReceiver and ParsePushBroadcastReceiver, ParseBroadcastReceiver in my manifest.

Comment: looking [at this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) you can subclass the `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` class and then decide how you want to handle receiving notifications. I would recommend reading that whole tutorial and clicking around Parse's docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @drees suggested in the comment, you can create a custom broadcastreceiver that extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.

Like this:

```
public class ParseCustomBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {

// Sample code
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
            final String notificationTitle = json.getString("title").toString();
            final String notificationContent = json.getString("alert").toString();
            final String uri = json.getString("uri");

//Create a taskstack builder - this is just sample(incomplete) to give an idea
            Intent resultIntent = null;
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

            // Customize your notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification_icon)
                            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                            .setContentText(notificationContent)
                            .setGroup(GROUP_SHORTR_NOTIFS)
                            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                    .bigText(notificationContent));

            int mNotificationId = 001;
            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, builder.build());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Add the following in the manifest.

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.ParseCustomBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

If you are following [this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) then the above manifest edit just requires you to change the android:name property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: would it be possible to add this class into an activity class and then access it?

Comment: how do you mean? whenever a push notification is sent via Parse, the broadcast receiver intercepts the incoming message/notification and then takes an action based on the logic inside the onReceive method.

Comment: On receiving this, I want to call an asynctask which requires activity as a parameter. If I keep this receiver class in a separate class, I cant pass activity instance, so I need to keep this as an inner class within my activity itself.

Comment: you can fire up an activity/intent using the result intent in the receiver. But if you do not wish to bring any activity up and just run some async/background process, I think you should then consider starting a Service from broadcast receiver.

Comment: The issue is, I dont want to fire up a new instance of that activity, that is, activity should not be reloaded.

Comment: ah! So, you don't want to fire an activity if it is already open when the notification arrives? try using android:launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest for your activity and override onNewIntent() - here, you can implement the logic. Something on these lines should work!

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I finally resorted to broadcasting a new intent from this receiver class and creating a new broadcastreceiver in my activity to monitor for this signal, and then call my method from my activty. Worked like a charm :)